# Aggregating query - could someone check it for me please?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following Table:

```
DPR_TS  TIMESTAMP(6)    Y           
DPR_QOT_ID  NUMBER(10)  Y           
DPR_CLOSE   NUMBER(16,4)    Y           
DPR_OPEN    NUMBER(16,4)    Y           
DPR_HIGH    NUMBER(16,4)    Y           
DPR_LOW NUMBER(16,4)    Y           
DPR_VOLUME  NUMBER(16,4)    Y
```

There are many entries very frequently with same DPR_TS and different qots.  DPR_LOW, DPR_HIGH, DPR_VOLUME, DPR_OPEN could be NULL.

Please see this example:

```
DRP_TS            DPR_QOT_ID   DPR_CLOSE  DPR_LOW
30.07.2013 09:00  1            12         12
30.07.2013 09:00  1            12         12
30.07.2013 09:00  1            12         12
30.07.2013 09:00  1            12         NULL 
31.07.2013 09:00  1            13         13
31.07.2013 09:00  1            13         13
31.07.2013 09:00  1            13         NULL 
30.07.2013 09:00  2            17         17
30.07.2013 09:00  2            18         17
30.07.2013 09:00  2            17         17
30.07.2013 09:00  2            17         17
30.07.2013 09:10  2            15         15
30.07.2013 09:10  2            15         NULL
```

I wish to select these entries(most recent dpr_close, min(dpr_low), max(dpr_high), max(dpr_open), max(dpr_volume), all aggregated ny dpr_qot_id and trunc(dpr_ts))  from the above table:

```
    DRP_TS            DPR_QOT_ID   DPR_CLOSE  DPR_LOW
    30.07.2013 09:00  1            12         12 
    31.07.2013 09:00  1            13         13
    30.07.2013 09:10  2            15         15
```

I have tried this query:

```
      SELECT dpr_qot_id
          ,trunc(dpr_ts)
          ,(SELECT (dpr_close)
             FROM tti_qot_load_ma t1
            WHERE t1.dpr_qot_id = (t2.dpr_qot_id)
                  AND dpr_ts = (SELECT MAX(dpr_ts)
                                  FROM tti_qot_load_ma t3
                                 WHERE t1.dpr_qot_id = t3.dpr_qot_id)
                  AND rownum = 1)
          ,MAX(t2.dpr_high)           
          ,MIN(t2.dpr_low)           
          ,MAX(t2.dpr_open)           
          ,MAX(t2.dpr_volume)    
      FROM tti_qot_load_ma t2
GROUP BY dpr_qot_id, trunc(dpr_ts)
```

Anyhow could someone have a look at it and tell me if it is correct? 
The explain plain looks like fine to me. Anyhow it takes really long when I run it.
I'm not sure if my query is right. The table has many entries btw.

Comment: Please explain your "want to select these entries" example. Are you trying to find the maximum `dpr_high` for a given `dpr_ts` and `dpr_qot_id`? And for `drp_close`, are you trying to find the maximum, minimum, or most recent? If so, how do you determine most recent within a given timestamp? And finally, are you intending to get the maximum `dpr_volume` or the sum or average?

Comment: I have changed your title because this is not a simple query.  There appear to be some complicated business rules in play which you have failed to explain.  Apart from anything else, the projection of your posted query doesn't match your desired output.

Comment: I have edited my question, so, that it must be clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see if the following meets your needs:

```
SELECT DRP_TS, MAX(DPR_QOT_ID), MIN(DPR_CLOSE), MAX(DPR_LOW)
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY DRP_TS
ORDER BY DRP_TS;
```

You can use the following demo to verify: **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f3684/4)**.

It produces the following result:

```
DRP_TS      MAX(DPR_QOT_ID) MIN(DPR_CLOSE)  MAX(DPR_LOW)
30.07.2013 09:00        2                 12    17
30.07.2013 09:10        2                 15    15
31.07.2013 09:00        1                 13    13
```

It seems to match yours.

Comment: I think the original poster probably wants to also group by and order by `dpr_qot_id`?

Comment: @Aaron Friel - Since OP is not forthcoming with any explanation, I was reproducing his supposed output.  Not sure whether this is what s/he needs.

Comment: I don't want min dpr_close. I want the entry with the highest dpr_ts for that. And as PM 77-1 mentioned I also want to group by dpr_qot_id.

Comment: @PM77-1: I'd forth come. You seems to be impatient. Was night here as I wrote my question.

Comment: @MaMu - After looking at my query and SQL Fiddle, do you understand how to achieve what you need yourself?  The template stays the same: `aggregate functions` (**MIN** or **MAX**) and `GROUP BY` clause.